# How to conditionally scale values in Keras Lambda layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensor

The input tensor `rnn_pv` is of shape `(?, 48, 1)`. I want to scale every element in this tensor, so I try to use `Lambda` layer as below:

```
rnn_pv_scale = Lambda(lambda x: 1 if x >=1000 else x/1000.0 )(rnn_pv)
```

But it comes the error:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

So what is the proper way to realize this function ?

Comment: I believe you want to use `x.get_shape()` of some index (from what I see `x.get_shape()[0]`) because you are comparing `tf.Tensor` object to `integer` (1000)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use Python control flow statements such as if-else statements to perform conditional operations in the definition of a model. Instead you need to use methods defined in Keras backends. Since you are using TensorFlow as the backend you can use `tf.where()` to achieve that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

scaled = Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(x >= 1000, tf.ones_like(x), x/1000.))(input_tensor)
```

Alternatively, to support all the backends, you can create a mask to do this:

```
from keras import backend as K

def rescale(x):
    mask = K.cast(x >= 1000., dtype=K.floatx())
    return mask + (x/1000.0) * (1-mask)

#...
scaled = Lambda(rescale)(input_tensor)
```

---

**Update:** An alternative way to support all the backends is to use `K.switch` method:

```
from keras import backend as K

scaled = Lambda(lambda x: K.switch(x >= 1000., K.ones_like(x), x / 1000.))(input_tensor)
```