# How to perform comparative assignment to tensor variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here I have x and y as tensor variable of shape: [5,256,256,3] each and dtype: float32. Here, 5 is my batch size and [256,256,3] is the three channel image. I am trying to perform something like this:

```
y[y>255] = 255
x[x > 255] = 255
y[y<0] = 0
x[x<0] = 0

#I have tried to create two tf variables by:
var_255 = tf.Variable(tf.ones(tf.shape(x), tf.float32))*255  
var_0 =  tf.Variable(tf.zeros(tf.shape(x), tf.float32))
#and tried to use tf.assign(). However, it still is not what I need.
```

I am getting this error:

> 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Do you want to do this in Keras or TensorFlow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally scale values in Keras Lambda layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53167108/how-to-conditionally-scale-values-in-keras-lambda-layer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
x_1 = Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(x >= 255.0, tf.ones_like(x)*255.0, x))(x)
x = Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(x <= 0.0, tf.zeros_like(x), x))(x_1)
y_1 = Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(x >= 255.0, tf.ones_like(x)*255.0, x))(y)
y = Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(x <= 0.0, tf.zeros_like(x), x))(y_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In TensorFlow, you can use [`tf.greater`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/greater), [`tf.less`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/less) and [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where).

Simple demo codes are below.

```
# TensorFlow 1.14
import tensorflow as tf  

x = [[254, 255, 256],
     [257, 258, 259],
     [252, 253, 254]]

condition = tf.math.greater(x, 255)

result_x = tf.where_v2(condition, 255, x) # tf.where is deprecated in 1.14

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
result = sess.run(result_x)
print(result)
```

```
[[254 255 255]
 [255 255 255]
 [252 253 254]]
```

---

And additionally, you can use [`tf.ones_like`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ones_like) instead of `tf.ones(tf.shape(x), tf.float32)`.

```
tf.ones_like(x)
```

Comment: I have tensorflow 1.13.1 is there a way to do this in this version? The tf.where_v2 is unavailable in tf 1.13.1 and tf.where throws a shape mismatch error in tf.where(...)

Comment: @TSimron, Try to change `tf.where_v2` to `tf.where(condition, 255*tf.ones_like(x), x)`. I think broadcasting is not applied in 1.13.1. In `tf.where`, second and third parameter should be match in shape.

Comment: Thank you @SiHyeonKim. I used tf.where in Lambda function and it worked like a charm.